# SQL Sorting without using ORDER BY

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two columns in a table: a number column (`MemNo`) and a value column (actually value column is computed). There are minus (-) values and plus (+) values. I need to keep minus values together and plus values together without considering the order. The order should be on number column. First I need all the minus values ordered by `MemNo` then plus values ordered by `MemNo`.

Output should be like this:

```
MemNo   |    Value
  1     |     -20
  5     |     -30
  6     |     -6
  2     |      5
  4     |     25 
  7     |      2
```

Comment: As a side note, without the use of the `ORDER BY` clause SQL returns results in a practically "undeterminable" order.  That is, optimizers will create plans that return rows in _some_ order, but usually **not** the one you expect; anything from that column nobody cares about, to which page was first in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when value < 0 then 1 else 2 end,
         memno
```

Comment: I asked the wrong question.And I got banned from asking questions again.I just tried to simplify the question.
Actually I have 4 columns and need to sort considering all 4.Like 1st Value1=0 AND Value2>0 AND Value3>0 `ORDER BY MemNo`,2nd Value1=0 AND Value2>0 AND Value3<0 `ORDER BY MemNo`,3rd Value1=0 AND Value2<0 AND Value3<0 `ORDER BY MemNo`, 4th Value1=1 AND Value2>0 AND Value3<0 `ORDER BY MemNo` and so on.How can i use above `ORDER BY CASE` with multiple cases.

Comment: If you got banned from asking questions, then start working on your existing questions to improve them instead of using comments to go on. The ban will only be lifted if you improve your questions. BTW deleting questions pushes you only deeper in the ban.

Comment: You should edit all your downvoted questions. A single bad question won't get you banned. Only multiple ones.

Comment: I have only asked 5.With this, 2 got down voted and I got banned.